# User-defined function is not working for other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPVRc.png)How to get around this situation?

As you know, the formula VLOOKUP in EXCEL shows the first value found in the table. Sometimes, you need to get all the values from the table as a list.
Therefore, I thought that there should be such a function (formula):

```
=VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE(DesiredValue, ColumnWhereWeSearch, ColumnFromWhereWeWantToGet,Number)
```

Code:

```
Function VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE(DesiredValue As Variant, ColumnWhereWeSearch As Range, ColumnFromWhereWeWantToGet As Range, Number As Integer)
```

VBA Code:

```
On Error GoTo VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE_ERR
n = 0
'we start to loop column if there is our desired value
For Each cell In ColumnWhereWeSearch
'we don't want to check up empty cells
If cell <> "" Then
    'if the cell has our desired value we number it using n variable
    If cell = DesiredValue Then n = n + 1
        'if this n equals our Number in function arguments we need to get row number in cell in order to find the value in the column where we want to get lookup
        If n = Number And cell = DesiredValue Then RowNumber = cell.Row
End If
Next cell
'here we just get column number our third variable
ColumnNumberResult = ColumnFromWhereWeWantToGet.Column
'Result:
VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE = Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumberResult)

Exit Function

VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE_ERR:
'this row gives "-" when error occurs
VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE = "-"
End Function
```

The problem is that this function is not working when I use in arguments ranges from other sheets, books.

And I roughly understand why. it turns out that I did not specify the name of the document, the sheet in the arguments, or in the function, and I need to get it somehow inside the function.

Comment: `VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE = Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumberResult)` - there is an implied `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: yes! i know. but how to adjust so if it worked correctly, understanding where the range is.

Comment: `ColumnWhereWeSearch.Parent` represents the parent worksheet of that range.

Comment: if i am not mistaken i tried to use `For Each cell In sheets(ColumnWhereWeSearch.Parent.Name).ColumnWhereWeSearch`   instead of `For Each cell In ColumnWhereWeSearch` and it didn't work out

Comment: You don't need to modify the `For Each cell` loop.

Comment: sorry i corrected my comment. i used `sheets` to refer to sheet name. `sheets(ColumnWhereWeSearch.Parent.Name).` and then `ColumnWhereWeSearch`

Comment: As I mentioned - you don't need to modify the `For Each cell` loop... you do need to fix `Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumberResult)` though.

Comment: you are genious!!!

Comment: worked out when i wrote `VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE = Sheets(ColumnWhereWeSearch.Parent.Name).Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumberResult)`

Comment: bro, i am new in this forum, can i mark your answer the best so if others could use?

Comment: I will add an answer and you can click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: there is one problem which we 've forgotten. how about another document?

Comment: No problem, as long as you pass the function a fully-qualified range. Note that my answer is not the same as what you put in your comments... I'm not using an unqualified `Sheets` call.

Comment: yes, it worked out too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implicit `ActiveSheet` in

```
VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE = Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumberResult)
```

To fix, use `ColumnWhereWeSearch.Parent`, which is the worksheet the range in question is on:

```
VLOOKUP_NUMBER_VALUE = ColumnWhereWeSearch.Parent.Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumberResult)
```